# Reset directly the content of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, zero-initialization

I have implemented a function that resets the content of the structure to which a pointer points:

```
template <typename Struct>
void initialize(Struct* s)
{
    *s = Struct{};
}
```

I have performance issues when `Struct` becomes big (above 10K) because `Struct` is created in the stack and then assigned to `*s`. I was wondering if I could improve it:

1. Is it possible to **initialize directly** `*s` without the temporary `Struct{}` object?
2. Should I instead evaluate the size of `Struct` and build it in the heap if it is big?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a static one and assign that? (it would be created once and then you'd just do the copy).

Comment: That would spare the creation of the object but not the storage in memory, which will also be allocated in stack.

Comment: What is possible depends on `Struct`. What are we allowed to assume about `Struct`? If `Struct` has something akin to a `clear()` method, then yes there is a better way to re-initialize the object. (Before you object to placing restrictions on `Struct`, remind yourself that your current code already places a restriction, specifically that `Struct` is default constructible.)

Comment: Since you don't check for `s` being null, you might as well have the function take a reference to give the calling code more freedom at no cost.

Comment: The "content of a pointer" is the address of an object. In the title you should be saying "Reset directly a struct being pointed to by a pointer" or similar

Comment: I need to clarify to everyone that I have no option to add a `clear()` method because these structs come from external interfaces and pre-compiled headers.

Comment: @Victor "*That would spare the creation of the object but not the storage in memory, which will also be allocated in stack*" - `static` variables are not generally stored in stack memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and @Borgleader That is true. However, would be worth the cost of storing in memory more than 10K of 0s in the `data` section of the program?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should probably use a reference; not a pointer. The point of this is to avoid null indirection bugs.

If the class is trivial and value initialise to zero (which is *typically* the case for most trivial types), then the optimiser should compile your function into a call to `memset`, without any need for initialisation of a temporary object. So there should be no reason to worry in that case.

You could call `memset` explicitly, although that is technically not portable to exotic systems in case the class contains certain types (for example, null pointer does not necessarily have the representation of zero).

> Is it possible to initialize directly *s without the temporary Struct{} object?.

Yes, if you're willing to change the requirements of the function. Currently it works for classes that are default constructible and move assignable.

You can avoid creation of a temporary object if you modify the pointed object directly. In following example, there are no temporaries of type `Struct` created:

```
constexpr void
initialize(Struct& s)
{
    s.member1 = T1{};
    s.member2 = T2{};
```

To make this generic, the operation could be performed in a member function. Thus, you could specify a requirement that the pointed class has a member function with particular name and no parameters:

```
s.clear();
```

You can combine both approaches for types which they apply to:

```
template<class Struct>
constexpr void
initialize(Struct& s)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Struct>) {
        // alternative 1, if you trust your optimiser
        s = Struct{};
        // alternative 2, if you doubt the quality of the optimiser
        //    technically may have different meaning on exotic systems
        std::memset(&s, 0, sizeof s);
    } else {
        s.clear();
    }
}
```

If you need this to work with some classes that conforms to neither requirement, then you'll need to specialise the template.

> Should I instead evaluate the size of Struct and build it in the heap if it is big [10K]?

You generally should avoid having public classes that large entirely. If you need such large storage, you could wrap it in a type that allocates it dynamically. Something like this:

```
class Struct
{
private:
    struct VeryLarge{/.../};
    std::unique_ptr<VeryLarge> storage;
public:
    // public interface
```

Comment: To be tricky, you could define `initialize(x)` using SFINAE to call `x.clear()` if such function exists, otherwise execute `x = X{}`

Comment: @M.M I prefer my new suggestion of conditioning on triviality of the class. This way the function never constructs a non-trivial temporary which is a good property to have. Sometimes failure to compile can be more useful than generality.

Comment: Are you sure that `(Struct* s) { *s = {} }` and `(Struct& s) { s = {} }` are optimized differently? The `*` operation is only a memory deferencing at instruction level.

Comment: @Victor No. The reason to use a reference has little to do with optimisation. It's to avoid null indirection bugs. Note that I had a copy-paste error in my examples, which may have been misleading. It's fixed now.

Comment: `s = {}` should be `s = Struct{}` as the former will match `operator=(int)` ahead of built-in move assignment

Comment: there's also the issue of `memset` to `0` not being the same as value-initialization for some trivially-copyable types

Comment: @M.M Thanks. Good catches.

Comment: I have tried with `memset` and compiler warns me: `clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘struct MyStruct’; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Werror=class-memaccess]`. I also do not want to do a low-level reset, because a struct might have some default values. Optimization tools also warn me that assignment `s = Struct{};` consumes stack memory. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Victor Your best option is to define a member function to clear the class.